# React project build production is not working in Xampp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Am developing a project in reactJS. In this project there is a login page, if user login successful then he redirects to dashboard page. This is working in locally but i Created a build folder and uploaded in Server. From server i tried to login, user logged in successful then it redirects to dashboard page, there its showing error called "The requested URL was not found on this server." Can anyone take me out of this problem. Here is the code

```
if (response.data['status'] === "Data not found") {
    alert("Enter valid credentials")
    window.location.reload();
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify(response.data))
    window.open("/Foldername/Dashboard", "_top");
}
```

This is the Routing Folder

```
<Route exact path="/Foldername/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell apache to serve the index for any files it can't find:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```